# Repeated lines from Jinja For Loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am new to coding and learning for Infrastructure as Code.
Trying to pull info from a variable YAML file within a Jinja file using a for loop. It is working but it is displaying the code two additional times and I am not sure why.

```
{% for item in underlay[inventory_hostname]['MLAG'] -%}
{% if item == 'Odd' -%}   
   neighbor 192.168.255.1 peer group LEAF_Peer
{%- else %}
   neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Sample of entry in Underlay.yml

```yaml
leaf1-DC2:
  interfaces:
    loopback0: 
      ipv4: 10.2.0.11
      mask: 32
    loopback1: 
      ipv4: 10.2.1.11
      mask: 32
    Ethernet3:
      ipv4: 10.2.2.0
      mask: 31
    Ethernet4: 
      ipv4: 10.2.2.2
      mask: 31
    Ethernet5: 
      ipv4: 10.2.2.4
      mask: 31
  BGP: 
    ASN: 65201
    spine-peers:
      - 10.2.2.1
      - 10.2.2.3
      - 10.2.2.5
    spine-ASN: 65200
  MLAG: Odd
```

The results are:

```
neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
```

But should be:

```
neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
```

I took the variable file down to a single device that only has the entry for `MLAG` once but that still produces two additional lines and do not understand why.

The goal is to create a for loop that looks at `MLAG` and if it is `Odd` then produce the one statement or `Even` produce the other.

Comment: More probably this happens because `underlay[inventory_hostname]['MLAG'] == 'Odd'`, and since a string is iterable in Jinja/Python, you have three line, because there is three letters in `Odd`.

Comment: Well doesn't appear that my 'For Loop' is working correctly either as it only produces the 'else' output when I run it against multiple entries in the YAML file that clearly have some 'Odd' and some 'Even' and in one case it produces a forth repeated entry.

Comment: Makes sense, `Even` is four letters, so you got four lines. You are indeed looping on a string.

Comment: Yes this is related to Ansible, updated the tags and added info to original post.  I understand now that it is iterating on the letters, not sure how to not have it do that and evaluate it as stated.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because a string is an iterable object in both Jinja and Python.

You can test this doing:

```
{% for item in 'Odd' %}
Displaying one line (because of `{{ item }}`)
{% endfor %}
```

That would give you

```
Displaying one line (because of `O`)
Displaying one line (because of `d`)
Displaying one line (because of `d`)
```

Your fix is as simple as dropping the for loop, totally:

```
{% if underlay[inventory_hostname].MLAG == 'Odd' -%}   
   neighbor 192.168.255.1 peer group LEAF_Peer
{% else -%}
   neighbor 192.168.255.2 peer group LEAF_Peer
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That seems to be working now.  Just for my understanding because I am not actually going through multiple items under MLAG I do not need the loop as I am only validate the state of a single entry?

Comment: This could actually be a one liner: `neighbour 192.168.255.{{ underlay[inventory_hostname]['MLAG'] == 'Odd' | ternary(1,2) }} peer group LEAF_Peer`

Comment: `underlay[inventory_hostname].MLAG` is a string, not a list indeed. So, there is no need to loop on it. Even in the case you are targeting multiple hosts, the one parameter that is going to change will be `inventory_hostname`, not an element under `MLAG`.

Comment: @Zeitounator I don't know why, but I don't like the `ternary` filter. Looks redundant to the inline if to me: `{{ 1 if underlay[inventory_hostname].MLAG == 'Odd' else 2 }}`. But that's taste and colours.